# How to save image location in settings

Tags: c#, uwp

I develop an uwp app in c# / xaml.
In my app I use this code for select an image in picture folder and put the image on the background of a grid:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =  PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
     var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
     var image = new BitmapImage();
     ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
     ib.ImageSource = image;
     image.SetSource(stream);
    set.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = image, Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill };
}
else
{
     //
}
```

and what I want to do is: save the image location in application setting for later re-use 
And I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't save path to the file in UWP - the app also needs privileges, not only file location. You will likely get *UnauthorizedAccessException* when you get file directly from path - for example `C:\Images\image.jpg`.

There are two lists in UWP to remeber *StorageItems*, along with privileges:  [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br207457) and [MostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br207458).

When you add an item to such list, you obtain a token and this is what you should remember in your *LocalSettings* (for example). Then you can reuse such token to access the file/folder. Sample:

```
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // to save the token for further access
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyToken"] = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
    // rest of the code
}

// to get the file later:
StorageFile theFile = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync((string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyToken"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer` in following way:

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

localSettings.Values["some key"] = "your value"; // Store value in settings
var valueFromSettings = localSettings.Values["some key"]; // Getting value from settings
```

That way you can store and retrieve the file path, to get the path:

```
var filePath = file.Path;
```

and to get a `StorageFile` from a path:

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but how exactly can I do?  Can I convert a StorageFile in localSetting and a localSetting in StorageFile and how?

Comment: If I understand well I do: var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
var filePath = file.Path;
localSettings.Values["monimage"] = filePath;

Comment: ok but then I can't do var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(localSettings.Values["image"]); ... what must I do ?

Comment: after you read the value from the local settings you need to check if it exists (just a tip), and then cast it to a string. `var filePath = localSettings.Values["some key"] as string;`

Comment: This will have serious problems with file access permissions.